# Send email with php

Tags: php

Hi I have validated a form with php but something seems to be wrong in the code.After validating it should send an email ,but it doesn't.Here is my code:

```
  $firstName = $_POST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_POST["lastName"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$to = "fox.team001@gmail.com";
$subject = $firstName . " " . $lastName;
$headers = "From: fox.team001@gmail.com\r\nReply-To: fox.team001@gmail.com";

validate($firstName , $lastName , $email , $message);

function validate ($firstName , $lastName , $email , $message){
    if(!empty($firstName) && !empty($lastName)  && !empty($email) && !empty($message)){
        if(validateEmail($email)){
            $mail_sent = @mail($to , $subject , $message , $headers);
            header('refresh:5;url=http://www.foxteam.net');
        }else{
           header('refresh:0;url=http://www.foxteam.net/contact.php');
        }
    }else{
        header('refresh:0;url=http://www.foxteam.net/contact.php');
    }
}

function validateEmail($email) {
    $pattern = "^[A-Za-z0-9_\-\.]+\@[A-Za-z0-9_\-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9]+$";
    if(preg_match("/{$pattern}/", $email)) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the mailserver's error logs? Has your email gone into your spam folder? Have you tried using the same code to send a very basic email with no extra headers to addresses with different email providers?

Comment: Are you certain that all the ``$_POST`` fields have been populated?

Comment: yes all the fields are populated

Comment: I would also recommend to use a library like **Swiftmailer** (http://swiftmailer.org/) for sending e-mails. E-mails sent by the internal php-function tend to be categorized as spam by many e-mail-clients.

Comment: this should be a comment. delete please

Comment: I have checked the email is not in spam it just wasen't sent why that hapened I don't understand

Comment: try seeing what the $to, $subject, $messsage, and $headers variables are storing by echoing them out

Comment: something seems to be wrong with the validateEmail function if I take the portion of code and put it outside of the validate email function the email is being sent

Comment: Try this one: `$reg = "/^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/";`- should work fine with most e-mails.

Comment: @user985482 - you pretty much just solved it with that comment - I think it's a variable scope issue. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function validate ($firstName , $lastName , $email , $message){
    if(!empty($firstName) && !empty($lastName)  && !empty($email) && !empty($message)){
        if(validateEmail($email)){
            $mail_sent = @mail($to , $subject , $message , $headers);
            header('refresh:5;url=http://www.foxteam.net');
        }else{
           header('refresh:0;url=http://www.foxteam.net/contact.php');
        }
    }else{
        header('refresh:0;url=http://www.foxteam.net/contact.php');
    }
}
```

You need to include `$to` and `$headers` as parameters for your function - they're outside of its scope, so it can't see them.

Comment: You're welcome. Though I'd never have seen it if you'd not mentioned the code worked fine if you took it out of the function.